# Change event via radio button ionic 4

Tags: angular, leaflet, ionic4, radio-group

I'm currently working on a ionic 4 and angular project with leaflet for display weather forecast on map . I want to get the selected radio button value, on `(ionChange)` event in radio-group to change weather on map like wind , rain ..etc .

[image]

The problem is when i click on any radio the event doesn't change and l get overly data on map . I want to do is when user click on any option remove all markers and shows other markers .

Short code

```
      async getData(event) {
        console.log(event);

      if (event.detail.value="weather") {

      this.http.get("xxxxxxxx)
        .subscribe(data => {
          let f = data["vt1observation"]

            new L.Marker([this.cities.duhok.lat, this.cities.duhok.lng], {
              icon: new L.DivIcon({
                className: 'my-div-icon',
                html: `<div style="width: 45px";>
            <img src="assets/icon/${f.icon}.png"/ style="width:20px;">
            <span style="color:white">${f.temperature}C</span></div>`
              })
            }).addTo(this.map);

        })

        }  else if (event.detail.value="wind") {

      this.http.get("xxxxxxxx)
        .subscribe(data => {
          let f = data["vt1observation"]

            new L.Marker([this.cities.duhok.lat, this.cities.duhok.lng], {
              icon: new L.DivIcon({
                className: 'my-div-icon',
                html: `<div style="width: 45px";>
            <img src="assets/icon/${f.icon}.png"/ style="width:20px;">
            <span style="color:white">${f.wind}</span></div>`
              })
            }).addTo(this.map);

        })

}
```

console.log(event);

[image]

Html

```
<ion-list>
        <ion-radio-group (ionSelect)="getData($event)" [(ngModel)]="datails">

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>forecast</ion-label>
            <ion-radio slot="start" value="weather" checked></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>wind</ion-label>
            <ion-radio slot="start" value="wind" ></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>humd</ion-label>
            <ion-radio slot="start" value="h"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>rain</ion-label>
            <ion-radio slot="start" value="rain"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-radio-group>
      </ion-list>
```

Comment: can you add this `console.log(event);`log to question..

Comment: i added you can check it

Comment: could you check whether your IF condition is right (event.detail.value="weather") instead of (event.detail.value==='weather')?

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI , the value he is changed now , but l have overly data mix !! . it should remove previously data then show new data

Comment: In which line you are getting cannor read property 'value' of null...(in event.detail.value ???? ) means we are getting either event or detail as null .....

Comment: Yes getting detail as null when i run my app . to showing the data i have to chose another value even to show

Comment: your problem is solved then?

Comment: no :( l am try to post new question about overlapping markers while l am change event

Answer (score 0):

This is where the problem is

```
 if (event.detail.value="weather") {
```

it should be

```
 if (event.detail.value === "weather") {
```

you are assigning the value to `event.detail.value` but you need compare with it.

I hope this resolves the issue.. :)

Comment: the value he is changed now , but l have overly data mix !! . it should remove previously data then show new data

Comment: this.http.get("xxxxxxxx), check here what is the data you are sending to server.. maybe that is what causes problems,,,

Comment: but when i got mix data while i change values ?

Comment: you are using same cities to show the data from this line , `[this.cities.duhok.lat, this.cities.duhok.lng]`..

Comment: Okay, but now when i run app l got empty map and error shows `Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI l it same . i only updated `event.detail.value === "weather"` in if statement